# Programmatically determine via ifdef if a label is defined within a Translation Unit

Tags: c++, label, conditional-compilation

I have the following bit of code, I expect that given cstdio is included that the first line will be printed, however the second line is printed.

What am I doing wrong? is it possible to know if labels such as printf or strncmp or memcpy have been defined in the current translation unit at compile time?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
   #ifdef printf
      std::cout << "printf is defined.\n";
   #else
      std::cout << "printf NOT defined!\n";
   #endif
   return 0;
}
```

Is the reason because the preprocessor is run before variables and labels are introduced into the scope/TU?

In short is the following code bogus? :

http://code.google.com/p/cmockery/source/browse/trunk/src/example/calculator.c#35

Comment: Standard library functions like `printf` are *not* preprocessor macros (or "labels," as you call them). You cannot use the preprocessor to programmatically detect if they are defined. What are you actually trying to do with that information?

Comment: `ifdef` doesn't work on functions definitions, variables, or anything like that...it works on things that have been defined through the `#define` pre-processor directive.

Comment: Put another way, the **only** symbols that the preprocessor can test with `#ifdef` are symbols created with `#define` or via the command line with -D. Preprocessor symbols are **not** the names of functions. As John Calsbeek asked, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek: I've updated the question with the bit of code that initiated my investigations.

Comment: @XanderTulip The entire purpose of that code is to detect if someone *else* has happened to define a macro with the same name as `printf`, and if so to remove that definition so that they can replace `printf` with something of their own choosing. That condition only runs if there's a macro definition of `printf`, not if `printf` is defined in general.

Comment: The code might not automatically be bogus just because it does the #ifdef printf. Many years ago (the '80's), I used a system with weird `#define printf(...) fprintf(stdout, ...)` (I honestly can't remember how the arguments worked) Maybe that technique is still used somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#ifdef` only applies to preprocessor macros, defined with `#define`, not to symbols like function names and variables.  You can imagine the preprocessor as an actual separate preliminary step, like running your code through a perl script, that occurs before the "real" compiler gets a crack at it.

So there is no programmatic way to check whether symbols like `printf` are defined in the current scope.  If you use one and it's not defined, you'll get a compiler error.  The normal thing to do is to `#include` a header file with the required definition in the source file where you reference it, not to write a source file that will adapt itself to different possible sets of headers.

As a hack, and depending on your environment and specific problem, the header file that does define `printf` (or whatever function you care about) may also contain some preprocessor `#define`s that you could check for.

Comment: `may also contain` - definitely WILL also contain.

Comment: @suddnely_me -- not necessarily.  For example, a private header file not from the standard libraries might not contain any guards (I know -- ech), or in some compilers the guard might be a `#pragma once` rather than a `#define`

Comment: OK, I agree, it's rather `should`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the guards from original include files to determine if they were included and, consequently, functions were declared.

For example, `<stdio.h>` shipped with my MSVS2010 has `_INC_STDIO` guards. Thus your code should be like:

```
int main()
{
   #ifdef _INC_STDIO
      std::cout << "printf is defined.\n";
   #else
      std::cout << "printf NOT defined!\n";
   #endif
   return 0;
}
```

Note that this solution is environment-dependent, so you should create more complicated rules it you are supposed to support more than one build chain.

Answer (score 2):

Their are a large number of symbols in stdio.h which are `#define`d, and   it is imported by cstdio

So you could use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
   #ifdef stdin
      std::cout << "printf is defined.\n";
   #else
      std::cout << "printf NOT defined!\n";
   #endif
   return 0;
}
```

**WARNING** I've looked at the header but not tested.